# MVC 5 Unit tests vs integration tests

Tags: entity-framework, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-5, integration-testing

I'm currently working a MVC 5 project using Entity Framework 5 (I may switch to 6 soon). I use database first and MySQL with an existing database (with about 40 tables). This project started as a “proof of concept” and now my company decided to go with the software I'm developing. I am struggling with the testing part.

My first idea was to use mostly integration tests. That way I felt that I can test my code and also my underlying database. I created a script that dumps the existing database schema into a “test database” in MySQL. I always start my tests with a clean database with no data and creates/delete a bit of data for each test. The thing is that it takes a fair amount of time when I run my tests (I run my tests very often).

I am thinking of replacing my integration tests with unit tests in order to speed up the time it takes to run them. I would “remove” the test database and only use mocks instead. I have tested a few methods and it seems to works great but I'm wondering:

1. Do you think mocking my database can “hide” bugs that can occur only when my code is running against a real database? Note that I don’t want to test Entity Framework (I'm sure the fine people from Microsoft did a great job on that), but can my code runs well against mocks and breaks against MySQL ?
2. Do you think going from integration testing to unit testing is a king of “downgrade”?
3. Do you think dropping Integration testing and adopting unit testing for speed consideration is ok.
4. I'm aware that some framework exists that run the tests against an in-memory database (i.e. Effort framework), but I don’t see the advantages of this vs mocking, what am I missing?

I'm aware that this kind of question is prone to “it depends of your needs” kind of responses but I'm sure some may have been through this and can share their knowledge. I'm also aware that in a perfect world I would do both (tests by using mocks and by using database) but I don’t have this kind of time.

As a side question what tool would you recommend for mocking. I was told that “moq” is a good framework but it’s a little bit slow. What do you think?

Comment: Unit Tests are for testing the code ***you*** wrote, Integration Tests are for testing interaction with things ***others*** wrote.  You shouldn't eliminate Integration Tests, but they shouldn't be the tests you run every 10 minutes.

Comment: as a rule, good separation of concerns and Dependency Injection will allow you to test almost every function in your application as if it were the entire application by itself.  If your function relies upon the result of some other function/service/library in order to give a correct response, then it is most likely not refactored enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. Do you think mocking my database can “hide” bugs that can occur only when my code is running against a real database? Note that I don’t want to test Entity Framework (I’m sure the fine people from Microsoft did a great job on that), but can my code runs well against mocks and breaks against MySQL ?

Yes, if you only test your code using Mocks, it's very easy for you to have false confidence in your code.  When you're mocking the database, what you're doing is saying "I expect these calls to take place".  If your code makes those calls, it'll pass the test, but if they're the wrong calls, it won't work in production.  At a simple level, if you add / remove a column from your database the database interaction may need to change, but the process of adding/removing the column is hidden from your tests until you update the mocks.

> 2. Do you think going from integration testing to unit testing is a king of “downgrade”?

It's not a downgrade, it's different.  Unit testing and integration testing have different benefits that in most cases will complement each other.

> 3. Do you think dropping Integration testing and adopting unit testing for speed consideration is ok.

Ok is very subjective.  I'd say no, however you don't have to run *all* of your tests *all* of the time.  Most testing frameworks (if not all) allow you to categorise your tests in some way.  This allows you to create subsets of your tests, so you could for example have a "DatabaseIntegration" category that you put all of your database integration tests in, or "EndToEnd" for full end to end tests.  My preferred approach is to have separate builds.  The usual/continuous build that I would run before/after each check-in only runs unit tests.  This gives quick feedback and validation that nothing has broken.  A less common / daily / overnight build, in addition to running the unit tests, would also run slower / repeatable integration tests.  I would also tend to run integration tests for areas that I've been working on before checking in the code if there's a possibility of the code impacting the integration.

> 4. I’m aware that some framework exists that run the tests against an in-memory database (i.e. Effort framework), but I don’t see the advantages of this vs mocking, what am I missing?

I haven't used them, so this is speculation.  I would imagine the main benefit is that rather than having to simulate the database interaction with mocks, you instead setup the database and measure the post state.  The tests become less *how* you did something and more *what data moved*.  On the face of it, this could lead to less brittle tests, however you're effectively writing integration tests against another data provider that you're not going to use in production. If it's the right thing to do is again, very subjective.

I guess the second benefit is likely to be that you don't necessarily need to refactor your code in order to take advantage of the in memory database.  If your code hasn't been constructed to support dependency injection then there is a good chance that you will need to perform some level of refactoring in order to support mocking.

> I’m also aware that in a perfect world I would do both (tests by using mocks and by using database) but i don’t have this kind of time.

I don't really understand why you feel this is the case.  You've already said that you have integration tests already that you're planning on replacing with unit tests.  Unless you need to do major refactoring in order to support the unit-tests your integration tests should still work.  You don't usually need as many integration tests as you need unit tests, since the unit tests are there to verify the functionality and the integration tests are there to verify the integration, so the overhead of creating them should be relatively small.  Using categorisation to determine which tests you run will reduce the time impact of running your tests.

> As a side question what tool would you recommend for mocking. I was told that “moq” is a good framework but it’s a little bit slow. What do you think?

I've used quite a few different mocking libraries and for the most part, they are all very similar.  Some things are easier with different frameworks, but without knowing what you're doing it's hard to say if you will notice.  If you haven't built your code with dependency injection in mind then you may have find it challenging getting your mocks to where you need them.

Mocking of any kind is generally quite fast, you're usually (unless you're using partial mocks) removing all of the functionality of the class/interface you're mocking so it's going to perform faster than your normal code.  The only performance issues I've heard about are if you're MS fakes/shims, sometimes (depending on the complexity of the assembly being faked) it can take a while for the fake assemblies to be created.

The two frameworks I've used that are a bit different are MS fakes/shims and Typemock.  The MS version requires a certain level of visual studio, but allows you to generate fake assemblies with shims of certain types of object that means you don't have to pass your mocks from your test through to where they're used. Typemock is a commercial solution that uses the profiling API to inject code while your tests are running which means it can reach parts other mocking frameworks can't.  These are both particularly useful if you've got a codebase that hasn't been written with unit testing in mind that can help to bridge the gap.